# Spring - referencing children contexts from parent context

Tags: java, spring

I have an interesting use case where I'm considering writing a generic `FactoryBean` to choose an instance from one of two contexts.

Details:

- My parent context is called `root` and has two children: `legacy` and `newShiny`.
- The two children contexts are registered as regular beans on the root context.

Now my `FactoryBean` looks like:

```
class MyServiceFactoryBean extends AbstractFactoryBean<MyService> {
    @Inject
    @Qualifier("legacy")
    ApplicationContext legacy;

    @Inject
    @Qualifier("newShiny")
    ApplicationContext newShiny;

    @Override
    protected MyService createInstance() throws Exception {
        if (tossCoin() == HEADS) {
            return legacy.getBean(MyService.class);
        } else {
            return newShiny.getBean(MyService.class);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public java.lang.Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return MyService.class;
    }
}
```

It really seems like the solution to my problem, but making the parent aware of its children feels dirty and illegal (what world do we live in?).

So, is this a bad idea? Why? What problems can it cause? What are the alternatives? Or maybe it's an almost normal thing to do?

For a bit of background, I need to support two very different models that I want to hide behind interfaces and choose the implementation at runtime (yes, it has to be dynamic at runtime). I'm considering using different contexts for them to keep things cleaner and avoid interference.

Comment: How did you registered/defined such children context on root context?

Comment: That solution seems way to complicated, why do you not simply create a `FactoryBean` which returns the proper instance based on the property instead of putting it in an additional context. Also instead of using a `FactoryBean` use profiles. Define a `legacy` profile containing the old beans, a `newShine` for the new implementations. I wouldn't start to mess around with multiple contexts, as that will make things more complex and you will probably run into other problems.

Comment: @M.Deinum Separate contexts keep things cleaner, more obviously independent and not interfering.

Comment: @M.Deinum The problem with profiles is that as far as I understand, they are too static. I want to have both active at the same time (my app uses both implementations at the same time for different users), and I only want to have one active for a particular user.

Comment: Still the solution with multiple context feels to bloated and feels like using a canon to shoot that annoying buzzing insect in your room.  I would probably separate them in different configuration files, load them in a single context and use a proxy/factory to determine which one to use. You could implement the logic once and reuse (basically what you do now already but inside a single context).